Julia doc comment with a shell line (with $ symbol)
I tried to write a doc comment above
function main()

like so
"""
Program arguments:

    $ julia my_julia_program.jl DATE

DATE format should be `yyyymmdd`
"""
function main()

However, this resulted in an error:
ERROR: LoadError: syntax: invalid interpolation syntax: "$ "

My guess would be that Julia has tried to interpret this doc comment as an example code which is runnable. (Rust has the same concept - it is possible to write unit tests and examples in doc comments, which can then be run by cargo test.)
Can anyone advise me on what I should to do fix this? I wanted to include the $ sign here to indicate to the reader that this line is a command line which should be run from the shell. Hence the $.

https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/strings/#string-interpolation

You cannot put a $ sign in a doc comment without escaping it first.
Backslash (escape) is required:
"""
Program arguments:

    \$ julia my_julia_program.jl DATE

DATE format should be `yyyymmdd`
"""
function main()

